# Binded property not changes back using DataTriggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I try to make simple logic for 2 togglebuttons using binding to IsChecked property and DataTriggers for catching binded value chnaging in second ToggleButton like this:

```
<ToggleButton 
    ToolTip="{Binding Source={StaticResource CameraLocalization}, Path=ToolTips.SyncMovementXYZ, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Tag="{Binding Path=CameraAcceleration, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource CameraSyncLastSectionStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=Property1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource PinIcon}"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Property2, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource UnpinIcon}"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton
    ToolTip="{Binding Source={StaticResource CameraLocalization}, Path=ToolTips.SyncMovementXY, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Tag="{Binding Path=CameraAcceleration, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource CameraSyncAdditionalStyle}">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=Property2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource PinIcon}"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource UnpinIcon}"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

When 2nd Togglebutton unchecked, 1st button must also be unchecked, but as far as I see, property CameraAcceleration.Config.UI.IsSyncMovementXYZActivated not being set to false although IsChecked property of 1st button was set to false and because of this, when I uncheck 2nd button, 1st become checked again.
Expected result: 1st button must stays unchecked.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Post your code behind the XAML markup. You actually don't need any triggers, a two-way binding to both ToggleButtons should do the trick.

Comment: A have no codebehind for this XAML. I do need triggers at least to change buttons content depending on its state. Also I need binding to my properties like: Path=CameraAcceleration.Config.UI.IsSyncMovementXYZActivated, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to know current state

Comment: Are you using the `MVVM` pattern? If so, you could represent the state as boolean and bind the property to both ToggleButtons. If something set the boolean property, both ToggleButtons are changing it's state. I could write a detailed answer if that is, what you want.

Comment: The trick is that these 2 buttons need to be binded to different properties. The only thing I want to do - I described in my first post - nothing more. Is it possible to rich this using only XAML?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CameraAcceleration.Config.UI.IsSyncMovementXYActivated, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
```

This line might be the error. Change `Mode=OneWay` to `Mode=TwoWay`.

In order to update the property while interacting with the View, the mode has always to be set to `TwoWay`.

Comment: No, it has no effect, because IsSyncMovementXYActivated and IsSyncMovementXYZActivated its different properties.
In that datatrigger I only LISTEN to property changing. And that all.
One interesting fact. If I remove this line:
<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=CameraAcceleration.Config.UI.IsSyncMovementXYZActivated, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
everything works as expected. But in that case I loose my binding

Comment: Sorry, your property names are quite confusing and hard to differentiate. Please update your question and include the implementation of  `IsSyncMovementXYActivated` and  `IsSyncMovementXYzActivated`. I got another idea but I need the implementation in order to confirm that.

Comment: I changed property names not to confuse anyone. Hope now it is more clear. Think of then as about simple boll variables inside class with INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation, of course